# Appropriate way to draw to a JPanel for 2D Game development?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, 2d

I am wanting to make a 2D Game but I am having trouble finding the best and most efficient way to draw to a 2D Surface/Canvas using a BufferStrategy. I will be using a JFrame as the main window and want to draw to the surface of that. I would love to see some example code of how this is done (if this is a good way to do it) aswell as other examples. It would be great if someone could also explain some advantages and disadvantages of doing so.

I am currently adding my drawing class to my JFrame using 'frame.add(new Painter());' and then overriding the paintComponent method. The only problem I have found with this is it seems to only call this method once.

this is my Painter class:

```
public class Painter extends JPanel{

    public static Player player;

    public Painter() {
        player = new Player(300, 300);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        player.x++;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 32, 32);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Comment: And why would it call it several times? If you want an animation, you need to have a thread that moves your player and asks swing to repaint the painter in a loop.

Comment: Because I want to be able to continually draw to the screen so it shows updated player position etc..

Comment: 1) You mention paintComponent (correct) in the text but that code overrides `paint` (incorrect). 2) Unless also adding components on top of the rendering, consider using a `BufferedImage` instead.  Show it in a label & repaint the (image and) label when required (as per a Swing `Timer`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case, where your game needs to update the screen based on user actions only, you will need to call `repaint()` (on the JFrame for instance) when you update something.

In other cases, you need to construct a so called **Game Loop**, where you update the game state and render updated game state in a timely manner. A nice tutorial on a simple Game Loop with Java code can be found here: http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/

In case you develop a serious game, you should stick with a game engine for managing the game loop and other routine game development aspects. A good Java game engine can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/playn/

Comment: Although is an old question, I just wanted to clarify "Serious Games" is a term used for games created with other purpose than entertaining like educate or marketing. I think you meant "real game" or "complete game" perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

For a game loop and an efficient way to printing to the screen for game objects and others(images, explosions, etc), you need a timing mechanism and a JFrame to print to over and over again, while at the same time, getting updates from the player and the game state itself.

First, you need a main method, and im going to guess that you are pretty new to this type of field in java so I will break it down for you as fast and clearly as possible.

```
public static main(String[] args)
{
  yourClassName game = new yourClassName();
  game.run();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

This main method is doing 2 things first, creating an object to your run method (because static references are not recommended for game loops) and then calling that method with your newly created object. When that run method is done, the system will exit the program.

Now im not going into full detail here but once you have the run method running you need an init method that will only run once. In this method, you are going to create your JFrame that you are rendering to. That is fairly simple to do so, so i will not go any farther in creating a JFrame class. However your Run method should look something like this...

```
void Run()
{
   init();
   while(isRunning)
   {
     update();
     draw();

     time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

            if (time > 0) 
            {
                try 
                { 
                        Thread.sleep(time); 
                } 
                catch(Exception e){} 
            }

   }
}
```

This method will slow the computing speed to a certain fps that you desire(in this case the fps variable is named fps for show).

Now in your update method, you will have your keyBinding and other stuff to look for changes with the keyboard or mouse(and in my case currently, a server). Most people dont know how to print or draw to the JFrame without taking in a paramitor that the Repaint method requires, so we are going to override that by adding double buffering.

```
BufferedImage backBuffer;
```

In the initialize method you will add

```
backBuffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(),getHeight(),
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
```

In the draw method you will have...

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();

Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
```

And with those you have the ability to draw to the JFrame created by the init class(also, by doing this, you have the ability to draw from any class or thread to decrease the processing load).

To see if it works, go ahead and use the `bbg.fillRect(updateX,updateY,5,5)`

The updateX and updateY represent variables that you use to update the location of the rectangle. Save them as a global variable or a public variable saved in a character class.

And if all else fails, here is sample code that i have used for creating my own game engine...

```
import input.InputHandler; 

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 

/** 
 * Main class for the game 
 */ 
public class GameTutorial extends JFrame 
{        
    boolean isRunning = true; 
    int fps = 30; 
    int windowWidth = 500; 
    int windowHeight = 500; 

    BufferedImage backBuffer; 
    Insets insets; 
    InputHandler input; 

    int x = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
            GameTutorial game = new GameTutorial(); 
            game.run(); 
            System.exit(0); 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method starts the game and runs it in a loop 
     */ 
    public void run() 
    { 
            initialize(); 

            while(isRunning) 
            { 
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

                    update(); 
                    draw(); 

                    //  delay for each frame  -   time it took for one frame 
                    time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis()-          time); 

                    if (time > 0) 
                    { 
                            try 
                            { 
                                    Thread.sleep(time); 
                            } 
                            catch(Exception e){} 
                    } 
            } 

            setVisible(false); 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method will set up everything need for the game to run 
     */ 
    void initialize() 
    { 
            setTitle("Game Tutorial"); 
            setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight); 
            setResizable(false); 
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            setVisible(true); 

            insets = getInsets(); 
            setSize(insets.left + windowWidth + insets.right, 
                            insets.top + windowHeight + insets.bottom); 

        backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight,   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
            input = new InputHandler(this); 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method will check for input, move things 
     * around and check for win conditions, etc 
     */ 
    void update() 
    { 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) 
            { 
                    x += 5; 
            } 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) 
            { 
                    x -= 5; 
            } 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method will draw everything 
     */ 
    void draw() 
    {               
            Graphics g = getGraphics(); 

            Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); 

            bbg.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
            bbg.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); 

            bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
            bbg.drawOval(x, 10, 20, 20); 

            g.drawImage(backBuffer, insets.left, insets.top, this); 
    } 
}
```

I hope this helps and I know this may be a VERY late answer but i have yet to see one decent java game engine that was simple to understand and use and fun to work with. Hope you stay with it and happy programming!!!